# Sentry: beforeSend is called mutliple times

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, sentry

I have a react-native app with redux. I want to fetch a PUT request with data when Sentry logs an error. I’m new in Sentry and I use this in my App.js:

```
Sentry.init({
  dsn: ...,
  enableInExpoDevelopment: true,
  debug: true,

  beforeSend(event) {
try {
  fetchMyData(data)
  Sentry.withScope(function(scope) {
    Sentry.captureMessage('Error');
  });
  return event;
}
catch (e) { 
  return e;
}
  },
});
```

It works and the request is successfull the most time, but beforeSend is called mutliple times and in Sentry the events loop: Put Request -> captureMessage -> Put Request -> captureMessage… and so on.

Is there another way for calling the method when Sentry logs? The data is only defined at the moment when beforeSend is called. why is there this loop?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```js
Sentry.init({
  dsn: 'http://bla.com/12',
  debug: true,
  beforeSend(event) {
    try {
      // fetchMyData(data)
      // Sentry.withScope(function(scope) {
      //   Sentry.captureMessage('Error');
      // });
      const client = new Sentry.ReactNativeClient({dsn: 'http://bla.com/12'});
      client.captureMessage('test');
      return event;
    }
    catch (e) { 
      return e;
    }
  },
});
```

You need to create a new `Client` to send those events from `beforeSend`. If you call `Sentry.captureMessage` in `beforeSend` you create an endless loop if you don't check for a specific event.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be my answer. Is it possible to combine my fetchMyData with an Sentry error. So every time Sentry logs an error, the function is called once. If it is possible where can I call this function in your example? Thank you!!!

Comment: And when I use a new client the Error log in Sentry has not the whole informations. Perhaps I use the wrong way for my task of fetching data on error logging. But my old way made the right things: fetch my data on error and log my messages and also an set and Additional Context (which isn't shown in my example) ...

Comment: Sorry, I don’t fully understand what you are trying to achieve.